# MEANjs mongoose middleware + ngtable Pagination - all pages start at register 0 (pagination doesn't work)

Tags: angularjs, pagination, mongoose, meanjs

I'm following the ng-table example depicted here: http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1  using mongoose-middleware https://github.com/PlayNetwork/mongoose-middleware . My code goes as it follows.
list-insumos.client.view.html:

```
<section data-ng-controller="InsumosController" data-ng-init="find()">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Insumos</h1>
    </div>      
    <table ng-table="tableParams">
        <tr ng-repeat="insumo in $data">
            <td data-title="'Nombre'"> {{insumo.name}}</td>
....
```

insumos.server.controller.js:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    errorHandler = require('./errors.server.controller'),
    Insumo = mongoose.model('Insumo'),
    _ = require('lodash');

 .....
/**
 * List of Insumos
 */
exports.list = function(req , res){

    var count = req.query.count || 5;
    var page = req.query || 1   ; 

    var options = {
        filters : {
            mandatory : { contains : req.query.filter       }
        },
        sort : {
            asc : '_id',                
        },
        start: (page-1)*count,
        count: count
    };

    Insumo
        .find()
        .keyword(options)
        .filter(options)
        .order(options)
        .page(options,   function (err, insumos) {
                if (!err) {
                    //console.log(insumos.results); //this gives me the array I was looking for
                   ** res.jsonp(insumos); ** // the good stuff in insumos.results but I need to pass this in order to make the client controller take it as an object and use it for pagination in insumos.client.controller
                } else {    console.log(err);     }
            });
};
....
```

insumos.client.controller.js:

```
'use strict';

// Insumos controller
angular.module('insumos').controller('InsumosController',   ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Insumos', **'ngTableParams' ** , '$filter',  function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Insumos, **ngTableParams**, $filter) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;

        var params = {
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 5,          // count per page
        };
        var settings = {
            total: 0,           // length of data
            getData: function($defer, params) {
                Insumos.get(params.url(), function(response){
                    params.total(response.total);
                    $defer.resolve(response.results); //creates an obj $data with the  api results ("results" type is object, althought it should be Array... it is an object that contains 5 arrays)
                });
            }};

        $scope.tableParams = new **ngTableParams**(params, settings); //I get a warning here saying I need to make this uppercase, but I think it's cool to leave it like that
.....
```

---

Now ... I'm getting my list with 5 items (that's good). When I click the table action button to display 10 items, it works perfectly, it shows me the first ten items (total existing items: 13). All good so far. I click on "next page" and nothing happens. I check on the console and it says:

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$resource/badcfg?p0=array&p1=object
```

so I *console.log (typeof(response.results) +' - --- - '+ response.results)*  and I get

```
object - --- - [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

So ... I'm kinda stuck here ... should I do a *for* and push each result to $defer.resolve ? I tried every trick I knew about turning an object to an array and didn't change anything
Does anyone know what it is supposed to receive?

---

Still.. the list is filled... with the first five items. I checked the "network" tab and watched what happened every time I clicked on the "next page" button
And it seems like all the pages have the same first 5 items.. the **same** first 5 items. No matter which page I'm in, it always starts at item 0.

```
    options: {filters: {mandatory: {}}, sort: {asc: "_id"}, start: 0, count: "5"}
    count: "5"
    filters: {mandatory: {}}
    sort: {asc: "_id"}
    start: 0
    results: [{_id: "550763b325a55de01172d182", user: "5507633625a55de01172d180", __v: 0,…},…]
    0: {_id: "550763b325a55de01172d182", user: "5507633625a55de01172d180", __v: 0,…}
    1: {_id: "550763ba25a55de01172d183", user: "5507633625a55de01172d180", __v: 0,…}
    2: {_id: "550832c26a3755ec289ecabf", user: "5507633625a55de01172d180", __v: 0,…}
    3: {_id: "55087480332393bb3bb11ca3", user: "5507633625a55de01172d180", __v: 0,…}
    4: {_id: "550878d9a3b14ece3d112b6d", user: "5507633625a55de01172d180", __v: 0,…}
    total: 13
```

No matter which count or which page I set, it always starts at item 0

```
insumos?count=10&page=1  - GET  304 Not Modified
insumos?count=10&page=2  - GET  304 Not Modified
insumos?count=5&page=1    - GET 304 Not Modified
insumos?count=5&page=2    - GET 304 Not Modified
insumos?count=5&page=3    - GET 304 Not Modified
```

---

So the quuestions are:

1- why is the pagination  it not changing the items in the list? How can I make it work?
2- Why is that "expected and Array but got an Object" error? How can I get rid of it?

A Million Thanks in advance to anyone reading and taking the time to respond

Answer (score 0):

I've found, thanks to a generous friend , that there was a mistake in front of my nose all the time:
It wasn't changing the page because in the file insumos.server.controller.js I had this code

```
exports.list = function(req , res){
  var count = req.query.count || 5;
  var page = req.query || 1   ;
```

that should have been

```
exports.list = function(req , res){
  var count = req.query.count || 5;
  var page = req.query**.page** || 1   ;
```

Thanks, Dwira Maulana!

I keep getting the console error
    Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$resource/badcfg?p0=array&p1=object

---- but my main concern is solved.... If anyone wants to contibute to solve this other thing I'm gonna be very thankful

Answer (score 0):

To fix that error, just need to change your angular resource return actions to

```
'get': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
```

, overriding the defaults.
Also, you should change from method `get` to `query`, as `get` is by definition used to obtain one record, not the list.

```
'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
```